# Open static html document using webapp2

Tags: python, html, css, webapp2

I have my folder set up like this:

[image]

in my `guestbook.py` file I have the following code:

```
import webapp2

LOGIN_HTML = open('login.html').read()
REGISTER_HTML = open('register.html').read()


class LoginPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(LOGIN_HTML)

class RegisterPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        self.response.write(REGISTER_HTML)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', LoginPage),
    ('/register.html', RegisterPage),
], debug=True)
```

This runs the code fine, but won't access `css` or image files from the folder. Why is this happening? How might I fix this?

**EDIT**

**app.yaml**

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

**login.html**

```
line 7:  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testctyles.css" />

line 16: <img src="imgs/bellogo.png" alt="UniCoreLogo" style="width:45px;height:45px;vertical-align:middle">
```

**testctyle.css**

```
body{
    background-image: url("imgs/greyback.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a proper answer to your question, I would need to see your `app.yaml` and also the HTML snippets where your `login.html` and `register.html` refer to the static resources. It could be that you haven't configured the app to serve the static files, or there is a discrepancy in the paths between the config and your HTML.  There's more information at the following links which should help:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Comment: Yeah, you need to edit your `app.yaml` so that it knows how to serve your static files (in this case, the contents of `img/` and your css files). The two links I've shared include instructions on how to do that.  As you have it configured now, it's going to try and serve every URL through your Python app, which is not necessary for the static files.